# How do I use web sockets to generate a table from mySQL whenever there is a change in the database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

I do have a specific question on using mySQL with node.js.
So I have this mySQL database which will receive data from elsewhere and I would like to show data on this react app in the form of a table and make it be updated with new data whenever there is a update to the database (insert of a data into the table from elsewhere) How can I do so?
Below is my code
Front end:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar";
import Axios from "axios"; //axios library to make requests to api
import "./Stats.css";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";




function Stats() {
  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []); 

  const updateCustomerContacted = (ID) => {
    Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {contacted: newContacted, ID: ID}).then(
      (response) => {
      setCustomerList(customerList.map((val) => {
        const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
        const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
        const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
        
        return val.ID == ID ? {ID: val.ID, name: val.name, email: val.email, counts_of_visit: val.counts_of_visit, latest_time_of_visit: dateTime, contacted: newContacted} : val
        
        
      }))
    })
  };
    
  //delete function
  const deleteCustomer = (ID) => {
    Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/stats/delete/${ID}`).then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(customerList.filter((val) => {
        return val.ID != ID; 
       
      }))
    })
  }

  //pagination
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
  const customersPerPage = 5 //change this number according to desired number of rows in a page
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * customersPerPage;
  const displayCustomers = customerList
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited+customersPerPage)
    .map((val, key ) => {
      const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{val.ID}</td>
          <td>{val.name}</td>
          <td>{val.email}</td>
          <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
          <td>{dateTime}</td>
          <td>{val.contacted}</td>
    
          <div>
            <select id ="contacted" 
                 placeholder = "Yes/No"
                 onChange={(event) => {
                   setNewContacted(event.target.value);
                 }}
                 
            >
             
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No">No</option>
              
            </select>
            <button onClick={() => {updateCustomerContacted(val.ID)}}>Update</button>
            <button onClick={() => {deleteCustomer(val.ID)}}>Delete</button>
          </div>
              
        </tr>
      );
    })
    //to account for the fact that total number of customers cannot be divided equally among the pages
    const pageCount = Math.ceil(customerList.length / customersPerPage);
    //page change
    const changePage = ({selected}) => {
      setPageNumber(selected);
    }

    //update contacted column
    const [newContacted, setNewContacted] = useState(0);

  


   
  

  {/*}
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(1);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("/time")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setCurrentTime(data.time);
        });
    }, []);
  */}
    
  return (
    <div className="dashboardcontainer">
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
        {/*}
      <h1>Customer Information</h1>
  */}
      </div>
      <table className="customertable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S/N</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Customer Email</th>
          <th>Counts of Visit</th>
          <th>Latest Time of Visit</th>
          <th>Contacted?</th>  
          <th>Actions</th>        
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {displayCustomers} 
        </tbody>
        
      </table>
      <ReactPaginate 
          previousLabel={"Previous"}
          nextLabel={"Next"}
          pageCount={pageCount}
          onPageChange={changePage}
          containerClassName={"paginationBttns"}
          pageLinkClassName={"paginationNumber"}
          previousLinkClassName={"previousBttn"}
          nextLinkClassName={"nextBttn"}
          disabledClassName={"paginationDisabled"}
          activeClassName={"paginationActive"}
        />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Stats;
```

In case you need my backend code

```
//set up express server
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
//set up sql server
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
//create a variable called db to make your SQL Statements
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "",
  host: "",
  password: "",
  database: "",
});

//GET REQUEST to database to retrieve customers information from database
app.get("/customers", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM customer_info", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//Update customers
app.put("/update", (req, res) => {
  const ID= req.body.ID
  const contacted = req.body.contacted;
  
  db.query("UPDATE customer_info SET contacted = ? WHERE ID = ?", [contacted, ID], (err,result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.send(result);
      
      
    }

  });
})

//Delete customers
app.delete('/stats/delete/:ID', (req, res) => {
  const ID = req.params.ID;

  db.query("DELETE FROM customer_info WHERE ID = ?", ID, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
     
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      
      res.send(result);
    }
  })
})

//check if backend server is running
app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Your server is running on port 3001");
});
```

Currently I'm using useEffect Hook but how can I make the table real-time such that it will generate/refresh table whenever there is a change to mySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

Maintain two variables:

1. lastPollDateTime
2. lastTotalRowCount

Maintain a column in the database `updated_datetime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Maintain a column in the database `inserted_datetime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

As soon as any row is **updated**, the updated_datetime will contain the time at which the row which were updated. In each poll, you can check:

`SELECT * FROM TAB WHERE updated_datetime>lastPollDateTime;`

In order to track the newly **inserted** row, you can use the total row count and updated_datetime, inserted_datetime.

`SELECT count(*) as currentCount FROM TAB WHERE updated_datetime>lastPollDateTime AND updated_datetime==inserted_datetime group by COL having currentCount>lastTotalRowCount;`

Update the front end if there are changes. At the end of each poll, update the two variables lastTotalRowCount, lastPollDateTime;

Another Approach,

Define a trigger on the table itself.

Here, you have to create the two triggers. One for update and another for insert as there is no way to combine these two events in a single trigger.

You have to also create a diff table(say: change_table), that is identical to your table(say TABLE_NAME) and have some additional columns(action, changesDt);

Update Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update BEFORE UPDATE ON TABLE_NAME FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO change_table 
     set action= 'UPDATE',
     col1=OLD.col1,
     col2=OLD.col2,
     changesDt=NOW();
END$$;
DELIMITER;
```

Insert Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update BEFORE UPDATE ON TABLE_NAME FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO change_table 
     set action= 'INSERT',
     col1=OLD.col1,
     col2=OLD.col2,
     changesDt=NOW();
END$$;
DELIMITER;
```

From nodejs:

- Poll
- Look for changesDt and row count to in `change_table`.
- update the frontend.

Comment: hello Ritesh thanks for the help! is it possible to use useEffect Hooks from react?

Comment: You can use useEffect hook to poll from react to node.js. 
When react makes request to nodejs in each poll, Nodejs will find changes [diff] and send a response to react.

Comment: Hi ritesh how can I do so? Do I just replace the const getCustomers to useEffect to use axios to pull data from mysql when the page is rendered. So when I visit the html page of stats.js it will auto render?

Comment: Hi Ritesh I am using the useEffect Hook now however, it will only update whenever the page is refreshed or rendered not when the database is changed which is what I need, appreciate if you have the Code for it!

Comment: Hi ritesh would appreciate your help for the use effect hook because I am already using it how can I modify it?